# How to set classes for an HTML reference from within the HTML code Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, elementref

I have a reference to a textarea

```
<*wrapper-component (submit)="tx1.value ? submit(tx1.value) : tx1.setClass('required')??">
<textarea #tx1> <textarea>
</*wrapper-component>
```

which I pass the value of into my **submit function**, is it possible to set classes for my `tx1` element from the HTML itself instead of creating a `ViewChild` property and accessing `elRef.nativeElement.setClass` with typeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd normally suggest using `[ngClass]` binding for setting CSS selectors dynamically. However, if you insist on using a template ref variable, you could use the [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method to set attributes, in your case `'class'`.

```html
<*wrapper-component (submit)="tx1.value ? submit(tx1.value) : tx1.setAttribute('class', 'required')">
  <textarea #tx1> <textarea>
</*wrapper-component>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I used ```tx1.classList.add('required')``` because I wanted to retain the classes already existing on the textarea element.